# How we get image type from a base64_string

Tags: php, html, sql

I got a base64 encoding string. Now i need to get string is a image type or not.
How it possible when image is in base64 string. I am very confused..

Comment: i got only "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAA.'" string not 'data:image/jpeg;base64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using

```
$imgData = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAA.';
$Imgpos  = strpos($imgData, ';');
$type = explode(':', substr($imgData, 0, $Imgpos))[1];
```

Comment: i got only "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAA.'" string not 'data:image/jpeg;base64